# TypeScript copy object's properties to create a new object

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, types, properties

I want to create a new object of type 'B' from the object of type 'A' that extends 'B'.
I've tried to copy properties of type 'B' from the object with type 'A' and that gives me an error.

Could you please help me to resolve this error or explain what I do wrong.
Here is my code example:

```
interface ThemeMeta {
    available: boolean;
    tags: string[];
}
const defaultThemeMeta: ThemeMeta = {
    available: false,
    tags: []
};

interface Theme extends ThemeMeta {
    name: string;
    domainName: string;
    lastUpdate: number;
    published: boolean;
    developer: boolean;
    pinned: boolean;
    id: number;
}

const defaultTheme:Theme = {
    name: 'Default theme name',
    domainName: '',
    lastUpdate: 0,
    published: false,
    developer: false,
    pinned: false,
    id: 0,
    available: false,
    tags:[]
};

const theme:Theme = defaultTheme,
    themeMeta:ThemeMeta = defaultThemeMeta;
let key: keyof ThemeMeta;
for(key in defaultThemeMeta) {
    themeMeta[key] = theme[key];
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAsIFsIFkJhzIDeAUMhcnAG5zAA2cARvRAFzJMD2XrcIAbnKVCAcwDOHcWCihRAbQC6QgL6kEXENOQATCPACu9MBmx4CcDqZz5CyALwlhFGnUYt2yePXEQANM7IYpLISqQqQqSgkLCIKNYoEAAekCA64miYNhZOlMggcDhSMnJCeTpcWHQgAHKFntKyIKJllIzSAKoADjpwkBwgBlhM0K0UXQYswOKYOhzcvBD8Y7oQ1BD0XF3Q8zx8goFdoCAQc5x7Swd5wGeDw6PhpOqa2nqGxglsCQ65lAVFyAA5AARfRwIxgIJZFD-CCAgLlSrVOoAwHwwLtMDdXr9ZAABgRlAmUxmpw43l8hIoenWm22UHJcB8-kOxzJXiZlMCNw4BMCrgYzFYjOZVKCcAkbDCESeGi0kLA0K+0J+b3BH2hYsVZlslgSutVYIh+osQlYkIA1hAAJ4cK3WrgwTI602kGBcKAACntyFAq3eJmhuoAlL8KNrsoR5PbFD8IxBozblOEgA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently type of `key` if `keyof ThemeMeta`, which mean `theme[key]` can be any type of available types of the values of `ThemeMeta`. in our case is `boolean` or `string[]`. so type of `keyof ThemeMeta[keyof ThemeMeta]` is `boolean | string`

When you then apply it to any of specific properties of themeMeta you got an error, because neither `boolean` or `string[]` cannot accept value of type `boolean | string`

What you can do is:

```
const theme:Theme = defaultTheme;
let themeMeta:ThemeMeta = defaultThemeMeta;
let key: keyof ThemeMeta;
for(key in defaultThemeMeta) {
    themeMeta = {
        ...themeMeta,
        [key]: theme[key]
    }
}
```

Comment: Yosef, thank you. Your solution removes the error. Though I don't fully understand your reasoning. As **Theme** type extends **ThemeMeta** that means that all properties of type **ThemeMeta** have got the same definition in type **Theme**, thus a property `tags` or `available` in both objects `theme` and `themeMeta` has got the same type  i.e. boolean or string[]  respectively. So `keyof ThemeMeta` is `boolean | string[]` and key variable works fine if we get a "key" value on any of these objects. There error happens only when we do an assignment: `themeMeta[key] = theme[key]`. Why?

Comment: Its not related to extention. if both where o f type theme, or both of type themeMeta you would get the same error. `keyof ThemeMeta` is `"available" | "types"`. ThemeMeta[keyof ThemeMeta] is `boolean | string[]`. when you want to assign something to `themeMeta[key]` without know if to expect voolean or string[] you must provide smth wich is valid to both types (`boolean & string[]`) and what you provide is `boolean | string[]`

Comment: Yosef, thank you for your explanation. Now I see why there was an error :)