# TypeScript - how to copy object A's properties onto new object B that extends A - worked on older ts version now broken

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a class `B` which `extends A`. I am trying to copy `A` onto `B` (since `B` has all the same properties (and more) as `A`).

Example:

```
class TypeA {
    propX: number = 0;
    propY: number = 0;
}

class TypeB extends TypeA {
    propZ: number = 0;
}

let A: TypeA = {propX: 1, propY: 2};
let B: TypeB = new TypeB();

//Here I want to copy A's properties onto B
Object.keys(A).forEach(prop => B[prop] = A[prop]);  //this how we did it on older version of typescript, still works in this example but won't compile in my new project

//now set B's non-shared property
B.propZ = 3;

//desired output {propX: 1, propY: 2, propZ: 3}
console.log(B);
```

That `Ojbect.keys(A) ...` line is how we did it on a project with an earlier TS version, but now it won't compile. In fact, in [this TS fiddle](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCeAHApgQWgbwFDV9RATgPaIAaAXNAHYCuAtgEbIHQC80ADANw56EkBNSrUbM2nHgF8sWUJBgIUAIWjIAHgBdkVACYKkaTL1z9EALWH0mLdtyzSsIZBuipKiw%20wymK0AIwANPjEiELQAEySPE4uSu4GKuxUyADucAkAFACUPFgA9HkAEszI0ACS0ClgVC4aRNDAJPCuAOQwpswaAJbIMEQ19UpYAPIMAFbIwBoAdADWyPAQGahZ0wBmRAQAomDAABYZpmwAfNBKANqmALriqJchVzm4BRp7XTB7RGkppTpdOtAui5%20tAiCAdGIAG7MCBdEFENbQDQGCDAAhdRAaIIQbogECVTazGBdKhIt4wdRgOiIJzQBg0FwpfotFyNaldWkk6B0ZrJNL8CZTGQFKhfaAQZxnNrUfoAWggezABGQAI6BGRWCU01MZnEAGZcgUIbDlQCiAzEAzMD5KIFgoJKOEgjrKHrpI0qBAwchpiAiABzDJKHJAA) it will successfully run with desired results. However, there are errors on that line. And in my Angular project, it simply won't compile at all.

How can/should I do this now?

Also, yes I did look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71370716/typescript-copy-objects-properties-to-create-a-new-object), but did not find a working solution. The accepted "solution" there does not appear correct to me, despite not understanding it, I tried implementing it to my example with:

```
let key: keyof TypeA;
for (key in A) {
  A = {
    ...A,
    [key]: B[key]
  }
}
```

That really doesn't make much sense to me, but I tried it anyway before posting ‍♂️

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old "hey compiler shut up I know what I'm doing".

```js
Object.keys(A).forEach((prop) => { (B as any)[prop] = (A as any)[prop]; });
```

or

```js
Object.keys(A).forEach((prop) => { (<any>B)[prop] = (<any>A)[prop]; });
```

Some might say it's bad practice, but I think it's fine in this situation.

Comment: Boom boom, that's all I needed!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can store your keys in a readonly array and iterate the keys when copying the values. You also use this array to constrain the shape of the base class when defining it:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/PTAEBEFMDMEsDtKgC4AskGMD2BbHX5QBrSATwGdQFQBDUAJ0hoBMCAbU2++m0gLgBQ2eOWTEy5AIKgAvKADaAcgAO9LMoAaigDSgVa5QE1FAXVqVhogNwDkpZUgDSZaXLsOs0cRUnz4AVxwAI0h6ExsBEAgYBCQ0JCCackw2JMp-cgQAc1pCACJYHGU2SBxIeGRyPNAMVIy4rFBy8n9GFFQaZEiwWErQcg6HKnha-2ZISnjvShogrAA3SEFatNAAFXtIaULi0vK+gCVIbHpmAB5nUkldAODQgD5QAG8BUFBVdQ0+UFuQ+llQAAGGxvD5Gb6-UIA4ECAC+AiEqXIlA2DgAQk0AB7IcrMFGbaQvUEGABaEMCf2hNnhAhKYkk31RWwBTzBX1AAEZdGDDN8AEywmxRABSGTEdHgWBx322lEl4sICFENBGSE86wJ-QQGCQpCw-lAzFgzB+UpqBFE9H8GDEvWWFqwJQAdGwsFkABRPRTbETIFU69VMySKGXDZWqwME2EASisoCi0BobGSCLpoDRjM2GLkiAA7hr0e7YwiomtULBKBXQFgiKAQhgaPV2kgSBQuEhLdlQGxeqEk5XCFNGCx2JwaNxeIJoFh-u7LGJW9WvK2pNH0-JW2Y5L5NxE0U6wSSAQBmCKWR2QF1uz1omNxqJPd4Gdlcp-qXmgPnc0nfY+geFAA)

```ts
// Define the common keys in a readonly array:
const keysA = ['propX', 'propY'] as const;
type KeyA = typeof keysA[number];

// Define the base class using an "implements" clause to ensure that
// its shape includes the keys above:
class TypeA implements Record<KeyA, number> {
  propX: number = 0;
  propY: number = 0;
}

class TypeB extends TypeA {
  propZ: number = 0;
}

let A: TypeA = {propX: 1, propY: 2};
// Just a note: A is not an instance of TypeA since you did not construct it:
console.log({'A instanceof TypeA': A instanceof TypeA}); // false

let B: TypeB = new TypeB();

// This is ok because the keys are string literals in the readonly array:
for (const key of keysA) B[key] = A[key];

B.propZ = 3;

console.log({B}); // { propX: 1, propY: 2, propZ: 3 }
```